# Create table from HTML DOM Parser output and add class

Tags: php

I have created simple code to parse table `t-02` from https://wyniki.tge.pl/wyniki/rdn/:

```
<?php
include_once ("simple_html_dom.php");
$html=file_get_html("https://wyniki.tge.pl/pl/wyniki/rdn/");
$title=$html->find("table[@class=t-02]",0)->innertext;
echo $title
?>
```

The output is plain text without any formatting:

```
So. 28/01 N. 29/01 Pn. 30/01 Wt. 31/01 Śr. 01/02 Cz. 02/02 Pt. 03/02 IRDN PLN/MWh 147.22 137.89 169.02 178.91 178.97 177.62 181.39 MWh 72 720.40 75 460.00 58 887.10 64 432.20 64 198.80 67 817.40 64 899.10 SIRDN PLN/MWh 152.71 146.69 194.75 201.19 200.24 199.08 203.91 MWh 49 538.90 48 864.30 34 401.20 41 683.50 39 688.00 41 042.00 40 942.80 IRDN24 PLN/MWh 145.98 135.67  171.83  176.81  178.97  178.28  179.87  MWh 72 720.40 75 460.00 58 887.10 64 432.20 64 198.80 67 817.40 64 899.10 IRDN 8.22 PLN/MWh 152.22 144.41 195.66 200.91 199.91 198.69 202.81 MWh 49 538.90 48 864.30 34 401.20 41 683.50 39 688.00 41 042.00 40 942.80 offIRDN PLN/MWh 135.50 121.72 132.86 138.10 144.54 144.72 142.91 MWh 23 181.50 26 595.70 24 485.90 22 748.70 24 510.80 26 775.40 23 956.30 IRDN23.7 PLN/MWh 135.58 121.11 132.11 136.64 144.07 144.25 141.65 MWh 23 181.50 26 595.70 24 485.90 22 748.70 24 510.80 26 775.40 23 956.30
```

My question is, is there a fast way to change this string into a table with `class="table"` using php and how to achive this.

EDIT:
I have changed code and the output looks like a table but I have problem with cells position.
Code:

```
<?php
include_once ("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('https://wyniki.tge.pl/pl/wyniki/rdn/');

$table = $html->find("table[@class=t-02]",0);
$rowData = array();

foreach($table->find('tr') as $row) {
    $data = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {
        $data[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }
    $rowData[] = $data;
}

echo '<table>';
foreach ($rowData as $row => $tr) {
    echo '<tr>'; 
    foreach ($tr as $td)
    echo '<td>' . $td .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

results:

```
<table><tr><td>                                         Pn.                     30/01                   </td><td>                                       Wt.                     31/01                   </td><td>                                       Śr.                     01/02                   </td><td>                                       Cz.                     02/02                   </td><td>                                       Pt.                     03/02                   </td><td>                                       So.                     04/02                   </td><td>                                       N.                  05/02                   </td></tr><tr><td>              IRDN                 </td></tr><tr><td>PLN/MWh </td><td>                    169.02                      </td><td>                   178.91                      </td><td>                   178.97                      </td><td>                   177.62                      </td><td>                   181.39                      </td><td>                   155.71                      </td><td>                   149.48                      </td></tr><tr><td>MWh </td><td>                     58 887.10                   </td><td>                   64 432.20                   </td><td>                   64 198.80                   </td><td>                   67 817.40                   </td><td>                   64 899.10                   </td><td>                   76 358.00                   </td><td>                   74 026.90                   </td></tr><tr><td>                                                 SIRDN                                </td></tr><tr><td>              PLN/MWh                                 </td><td>                   194.75                                          </td><td>                   201.19                                          </td><td>                   200.24                                          </td><td>                   199.08                                          </td><td>                   203.91                                          </td><td>                   162.79                                          </td><td>                   155.66                                          </td></tr><tr><td>              MWh                 </td><td>                   34 401.20                   </td><td>                   41 683.50                   </td><td>                   39 688.00                   </td><td>                   41 042.00                   </td><td>                   40 942.80                   </td><td>                   55 808.00                   </td><td>                   51 619.40                   </td></tr><tr><td>                                      IRDN24                                      </td></tr><tr><td>              PLN/MWh                                 </td><td>                   171.83                                      </td><td>                   176.81                                      </td><td>                   178.97                                      </td><td>                   178.28                                      </td><td>                   179.87                                      </td><td>                   152.18                                      </td><td>                   147.13                                      </td></tr><tr><td>              MWh                 </td><td>                   58 887.10                   </td><td>                   64 432.20                   </td><td>                   64 198.80                   </td><td>                   67 817.40                   </td><td>                   64 899.10                   </td><td>                   76 358.00                   </td><td>                   74 026.90                   </td></tr><tr><td>                                             IRDN 8.22                                                                </td></tr><tr><td>                     PLN/MWh                   </td><td>                     195.66                                          </td><td>                       200.91                                          </td><td>                       199.91                                          </td><td>                       198.69                                          </td><td>                       202.81                                          </td><td>                       161.78                                          </td><td>                       154.61                                          </td></tr><tr><td>                                  MWh                  </td><td>                   34 401.20                   </td><td>                   41 683.50                   </td><td>                   39 688.00                   </td><td>                   41 042.00                   </td><td>                   40 942.80                   </td><td>                   55 808.00                   </td><td>                   51 619.40                   </td></tr><tr><td>                                             offIRDN                                                                  </td></tr><tr><td>                     PLN/MWh                   </td><td>                     132.86                                          </td><td>                       138.10                                          </td><td>                       144.54                                          </td><td>                       144.72                                          </td><td>                       142.91                                          </td><td>                       136.50                                          </td><td>                       135.24                                          </td></tr><tr><td>                                  MWh                  </td><td>                   24 485.90                   </td><td>                   22 748.70                   </td><td>                   24 510.80                   </td><td>                   26 775.40                   </td><td>                   23 956.30                   </td><td>                   20 550.00                   </td><td>                   22 407.50                   </td></tr><tr><td>                                             IRDN23.7                                                                 </td></tr><tr><td>                     PLN/MWh                   </td><td>                     132.11                                          </td><td>                       136.64                                          </td><td>                       144.07                                          </td><td>                       144.25                                          </td><td>                       141.65                                          </td><td>                       136.17                                          </td><td>                       134.67                                          </td></tr><tr><td>                                  MWh                  </td><td>                   24 485.90                   </td><td>                   22 748.70                   </td><td>                   24 510.80                   </td><td>                   26 775.40                   </td><td>                   23 956.30                   </td><td>                   20 550.00                   </td><td>                   22 407.50                   </td></tr></table>
```

I would like to move only the first row right for one column (like adding blank cell only to first row from left). Also I don't know why there are so many spaces in html code.

Comment: Yes, just echo the table tags around the data.  That's plenty fast.

Comment: @awiebe How to do that?